# ith order Selection in O(n) time

Tags: c++, algorithm

From "Introduction to algorithms" I am trying to implement the code as dividing n elements in n/5 groups, then recursively finding the median and then recursively finding the ith order statistics. Here is My code

```
bool isTrue(int *a, int *b)
{  
  if((*a) < (*b))
    swap(*a, *b);
  return *a < *b;

}

int select(int *A, int n ,int p)
{

    int *B[(n / 5) + 2];
    cout << (n / 5) + 2 << endl;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1, j = 1; i <= (n - 5); i += 5, ++j)
     {
        sort(A + i, A + i + 5);
        B[j] = A + i + 2;
     }
    sort(A + i, A + n + 1);
    B[j] = A + i + (n - i) / 2;
    sort(B + 1, B + (n / 5) + 2, isTrue);

 }
```

this is as far as I can go. Now I am trying to find the median of `B`, then do `B[median] - A` as pivot. But It doesn't seems right. In the book it says to recursively find the median of medians.I can't catch that. Any help?
edit: I also note that in the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) they didnt use any recursion!

Comment: Your comparison function should *not* swap elements.

Comment: owh ,thnaks... still, how would I find it using recursion?